# Expression.Lambda with Dynamic Input parameters

Tags: c#, api, expression

I'm developing dynamic Business Rule engine using Expression Tree. Hence I'm not sure about the number of parameters during compile time. I have to create dynamic input parameters. For this requirement, I'm using the Expression.Lambda like below, but its throwing error like:

> Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration

I may be wrong in the syntax. I referred to Microsoft site, they are creating Func with individual parameters, not array of parameters.

Even if there are around 16 parameters, they are individually declaring each parameter separately like `Func< T1,T2,T3,T4,T5...T16 >` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402862(v=vs.110).aspx

Is there any workaround instead of individually declaring can we pass as an array?

```
  var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda< Func< T[], bool>>(ruleExpression, pe).Compile();
```

In the above Syntax pe is the `ParameterExpression[]` array having multiple parameters.

In the above syntax instead of `T[]` array, if I use individual T elements, its working fine like

```
   var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda< Func< T,T, bool>>(ruleExpression, pe).Compile();
```

but the problem is the number of T will not be known during compile time.

Please correct me If I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: What about just Expression.Lambda(...)?

Comment: Expression.Lambda is the API function i'm using to create delegate from expression tress which was formed in previous operations or passed as parameter to other functions which i'm not show here, I just used the Expression tree variable ruleExpression where the Expression tree is stored

Comment: I tried plain Expression.Lamda as well

Answer (score 1):

Simple example of creation of a delegate with a runtime-assigned number of parameters. I consider this to be nearly useless (because you have to call the delegate through `DynamicInvoke`... You don't have any safety and you are using the slowest reflection execution method).

```
public static Delegate CreateLambda(int num)
{
    var parameters = new ParameterExpression[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        parameters[i] = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "p" + i);
    }

    // We sum all the parameters together
    Expression sum = parameters[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        sum = Expression.Add(sum, parameters[i]);
    }

    Expression body = sum;

    LambdaExpression exp = Expression.Lambda(body, parameters);
    return exp.Compile();
}
```

The `Expression.Lambda` will in truth genete a `Expression<Func<...>>` (or `Expression<Action<...>>`) where the `Func<...>` is calculated based on the parameters given, but `Expression<...>` is a subclass of `LambdaExpression`. If there are too many parameters for `Func<>` or `Action<>`, even the delegate type is generated at runtime.

and then:

```
int num = 5;
Delegate del = CreateLambda<double>(num);

// Note that we have to convert to object the various parameters,
// because DynamicInvoke uses a object[]
object[] values = Enumerable.Range(1, num).Select(x => (object)(double)x).ToArray();
double result = (double)del.DynamicInvoke(values);

Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", string.Join("+", values), result);
```

If you want to have a `Func<T[], T>` it is possible (and is probably a much better idea):

```
public static Func<T[], T> CreateLambda<T>(int num)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T[]), "p");

    // We sum all the parameters together
    Expression sum = Expression.ArrayIndex(parameter, Expression.Constant(0));

    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        sum = Expression.Add(sum, Expression.ArrayIndex(parameter, Expression.Constant(i)));
    }

    Expression body = sum;

    var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T[], T>>(body, parameter);
    return exp.Compile();
}
```

You simply use `Expression.ArrayIndex()`.

Then for example:

```
int num = 5;
Func<double[], double> del = CreateLambda<double>(num);

double[] values = Enumerable.Range(1, num).Select(x => (double)x).ToArray();
double result = del(values);

Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", string.Join("+", values), result);
```

Comment: Great Mr Xanatos,Thank you so much for explaining things and providing code sample. I try your approach .